# How to use koala gem to delete Facebook comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I am trying to use koala gem to delete my own comments on Facebook. The comment id is correct and I can delete it in Facebook graph explore. And the authentication part works because I can post,put_like and delete_like.

When I try:

graph.delete_object( @comment_id ) it showed this error:

type: OAuthException, code: 1705, message: (#1705) Selected wall post for deletion does not exist. [HTTP 400]

btw: my rails version is 3.2 and koala version is the latest one.

Anyone could help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook tell me that "Selected wall post for deletion does not exist."

Could you check object's fbid that you want to delete via 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer